# Prove that Alice’s solution x is equal to Bob’s plaintext m

Tags: provable-security

The answer to the second part of this question exists already.
However, I need help understanding how the first part of the question is solved.
I have a feeling that it must have something to do with FLT, although I can't figure it out.

Could someone post the proof or hint me in the right direction?
It feels like I am missing something very obvious although I'm not sure what.

> Alice chooses two large primes $p$ and $q$ and she publishes $N = pq$. It is assumed
>   that $N$ is hard to factor. Alice also chooses three random numbers $g$, $r_1$, and $r_2$ modulo $N$ and computes
>   $$g_1\equiv g^{r_1\cdot(p−1)}\pmod N\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }g_2\equiv g^{r_2\cdot(q−1)}\pmod N.$$
>
> Her public key is the triple $(N,g_1,g_2)$ and her private key is the pair of primes $(p,q)$.
>
> Now Bob wants to send the message $m$ to Alice, where $m$ is a number modulo $N$. He chooses two random integers $s_1$ and $s_2$ modulo $N$ and computes
>   $$c_1\equiv m\cdot{g_1}^{s_1}\pmod N\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }c_2\equiv m\cdot{g_2}^{s_2}\pmod N.$$
>   Bob sends the ciphertext $(c_1,c_2)$ to Alice.
>
> Decryption is extremely fast and easy. Alice use the Chinese remainder theorem
>   to solve the pair of congruences
>   $$x\equiv c_1\pmod p\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }x\equiv c_2\pmod q.$$
>
> (a) Prove that Alice’s solution $x$ is equal to Bob’s plaintext $m$.
>   (b) Explain why this cryptosystem is not secure.

Comment: Hint: $g^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  Can you write ${g_1}^{s_1}$ in terms of $g^{p - 1}$?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I think I get it. Is the jist of the solution the fact that if lets say: m = pk and m = qc, then since c1 ≡ k (mod p) and c2 ≡ c (mod q), m ≡ k (mod p) and m ≡ c (mod q)?

Comment: Not quite: $p\cdot k \equiv 0 \pmod p$ for any $k$.  Here's another hint: What's $g_1 \bmod p$?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Ooops, sorry, I meant m = k + pg, and m = c + qn, for example.

Comment: I am not quite sure what your letters all mean now; is $g$ the base, and $n$ the modulus called $N$ in the answer?  You don't need to write it out as explicitly as all that—can you follow the previous hints?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I am just trying to say that c1 ≡ m ≡ k (mod p), so m = k + pg, g being an integer. Also c2 ≡ m ≡ k (mod q), so m = k + qn, n being an integer. I understand that g1^(s1) ≡ 1 (mod p) and that g2^(s2) ≡ 1 (mod p) by FLT.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Thank you, sorry for the confusion, I'll have to learn how to write in-text equations and be more clear.